# Extra escape sequence adding on json via angular

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, nested-object

Extra escape sequence adding on json via angular the escape sequence is \\n instead of \n

```
generatePreview() {
    this.whatsAppRequest.messages = new Array<Message>();
    this.recipients.forEach(recipient => {
      let personalizedMessage = this.message;
      console.log(recipient.fields);
      recipient.fields.forEach(field => {
        console.log(field);
        personalizedMessage = personalizedMessage.replace(/\{\{[\*\d]\}\}/g, field);
      });
      console.log(personalizedMessage);
      console.log("File selected in preview " + this.recipient.url);
      if (this.attachment) {
        let message = new Message();
        message.recipients = new Array<any>();
        message.recipients.push({
          to: recipient.number
        });
        message.media = {
          caption: personalizedMessage,
          url: recipient.url
        };
        this.whatsAppRequest.messages.push(message);
      } else {
        let message = new Message();
        message.recipients = new Array<any>();
        message.recipients.push({
          to: recipient.number
        });
        message.messageText = personalizedMessage;
        this.whatsAppRequest.messages.push(message);
      }
    });
  }
```

this is my service code

```
sendWhatsApp(req: any): Observable<any> {
        let url = "";
        return this.httpService.postRequest(url, req, false, "https://example/whatsapp/json")
            .map((clientResponse: Response) => clientResponse);
    }
```

The request is adding \\n instead of \n

I Need to remove the \\n from the request How can I achieve it?

Comment: try `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(clientResponse))`

Comment: @DeepuReghunath I want to remove extra \ from the request. I tried to use your approach to remove the \ from request object using
 req = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req)); but still on the server getting \\\\n

This is the object that is being sent
`{"fallback":{},"sender":"+27xxxxxxxxx","messages":[{"recipients":[{"to":"+27xxxxxxx"}],"media":{"caption":"Hi First, welcome to the WhatsApp channel! \\n\\nTo. \\n\\nYour that you requested on First is attached. \\n\\nOur customer service number is +27xxxxxxxx .","url":"http://example.com/TEMP2.pdf"}}]}`

Comment: @DeepuReghunath Instead I want to send 
`{"fallback":{},"sender":"+27xxxxxxxxx","messages":[{"recipients":[{"to":"+27xxxxxxx"}],"media":{"caption":"Hi First, welcome to the WhatsApp channel! \n\nTo. \n\nYour that you requested on First is attached. \n\nOur customer service number is +27xxxxxxxx .","url":"http://example.com/TEMP2.pdf"}}]}`